# How to add new nodes / neurons dynamically in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

If I want to add new nodes to on of my tensorflow layers on the fly, how can I do that?

For example if I want to change the amount of hidden nodes from 10 to 11 after the model has been training for a while. Also, assume I know what value I want the weights coming in and out of this node/neuron to be.

I can create a whole new graph, but is there a different/better way?

Comment: Why do you want to add it on the fly?

Comment: You can try using dynamic TensorArrays, ta.stack() to make them into a tensor then matmul with activations. I'm not sure if this will work though --you need tensorflow to treat the values as variables and update them during the optimization step, and this is likely either not possible or very hard to implement (at least I have no idea how).

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak I want to make a neural network that grows over time using an algorithm I'm making

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating a whole new graph you might be better off creating a graph which has initially more neurons than you need and mask it off by multiplying by a non-trainable variable which has ones and zeros. You can then change the value of this mask variable to allow effectively new neurons to act for the first time.

Comment: Is there a way to change the weights on the fly? So when I unmask the neuron I can initialise the weights to it ?

Comment: The weights are stored in a variable and you can always session.run an op to assign any value you want to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

TensorFlow has many advantadges, but dynamic graph modification isn't one of them.

If you truly want to be able to change graphs on the fly, I recommend you PyTorch (http://pytorch.org/). Although it's much more recent than TensorFlow, so the documentation isn't as complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that `res` is output taking into account there are 10 hidden layers and let us call 10th hidden layer `layer10`. So what you do is

```
res = f(layer10)
```

where `f` is some function which operates on `layer10` and returns resulting tensor.

Pre-create `layer11` as some operation on `layer10` and `res2` as output from `layer11`.

Now running you just evaluate `res` which will use on 10 layers. When you want to use 11 layers use `res2`. If you know the weights then you can assign it like `tensor.assign(val).eval()`